# defaultValue en kendo ui cliente

Tags: asp.net, kendoui

Ya tengo mi modelo de datos,

```
schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "IdContacto",
                        fields: {
                            IdContacto: { editable: false, type: "number" },
                            IdCliente: { type: "number", defaultValue:  },
                            IdTipoContacto: { type: "number" },
                            Nombres: { type: "string" },
                            apellidos: { type: "string" },
                            Direccion: { type: "string" },
                            Telefono: { type: "string" },
                            Email: { type: "string" },
                            Estado: { type: "boolean" },
                            FechaCreacion: { type: "date" },
                            FechaModificacion: { type: "date" }
                        }
                    }
                },
```

Quiero que mi **IdCliente**, sea el valor por defecto, cuando hago mi consulta a la base de datos, es decir cuando voy a crear un contacto nuevo, no tenga yo necesidad de ponerle el **IdCliente**, porque se supone que ya lo traje con la consulta que hice.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, no pongas default value, en la BD que sea un campo Auto Incrementable, de esta manera te despreocupas...
Espero que te sirva de ayuda